Can anyone give me a direction to prove this inequality?
Suppose $$\prod_{i=1}^n u_i=\prod_{j=1}^m v_j$$ where each $u_i$ and $v_j$ are positive integers larger than 1.
I am suspecting that $$\prod_{i=1}^n(2u_i-1)>\prod_{j=1}^m(2v_j-1)$$
if $n>m$ and moreover in general that it will resemble the graded reverse lexicographic order in a way that if $n=m$ and
$$u_1\ge u_2\ge\cdots\ge u_n,$$
$$v_1\ge v_2\ge\cdots\ge v_m,$$
$$u_n>v_m,$$
then
$$\prod_{i=1}^n(2u_i-1)>\prod_{j=1}^m(2v_j-1)$$
again.
For instance if $n=2$ and $m=1$,
$$(2u_1-1)(2u_2-1)-(2u_1u_2-1)=2(u_1-1)(u_2-1)>0$$
and if $n=3$ and $m=1$,
\begin{align*}(2u_1-1)(2u_2-1)(2u_3-1)-(2u_1u_2u_3-1)&=2u_1(u_2-1)(u_3-1)+2u_2(u_3-1)(u_1-1)+2u_3(u_1-1)(u_2-1)\\&>0.\end{align*}
However, I became completely lost in attempts to prove this by mathematical induction. Even trying to prove it when $n=3$ and $m=2$ seems to be rather elusive to me.
At this point, I'm thinking that maybe I need to look for a more theoretical or structural approach but I'm not sure where to start.

Why does $v_1$ seems to be $u_1u_2$ or $u_1 u_2 u_3$ in your examples?

@Nolord because of the initial condition that $\prod u_i=\prod v_j$
